# Selenium with .NET: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated

Tags: .net, selenium, using

I am trying to read a value from . Here is the HTML code:

```
<select name="user_type" id="user_type" class="select">
<option value="0">Select</option>
<option value="1"> Admin </option>
<option value="1"> Agent </option>
<option value="1"> Butler </option>
<option value="1"> Ops </option>
</select>
```

This is the code I implemented in Selenium using .NET:

```
query_UserType = driver.FindElement(By.Id("user_type"));
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
query_UserType.Clear();
query_UserType.Click();
query_UserType.SendKeys(" Agent ");
string str_myEle2 = query_UserType.GetAttribute("value");
Console.WriteLine("New User Type is: " + str_myEle2);
```

It gives error "invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated" on line:

```
query_UserType.Clear();
```

I have no clue how can I get this fixed. Please help. Thanks

Comment: why are you trying to clear and insert text into a select tag? And what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to automatically select "Agent" from drop down and hit the 'Search'  button and results for "Agent" must get displayed. I tried removing query_UserType.Clear(), so I am not getting the Exception anymore, but I am not seeing the required result, it simply click on "Search" button without actually setting value as 'Agent' in the drop down. Somehow, I want to set value "Agent" in the drop down.

Comment: Sorry, here HTML code is:

    <select name="user_type" id="user_type" class="select">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="2"> Admin </option>
    <option value="3"> Agent </option>
    <option value="4"> Butler </option>
    <option value="5"> Ops </option>
    </select>

Answer (score 0):

The Selenium .NET library wraps the manipulation of `select` elements into a class called [SelectElement](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/AllMembers_T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_SelectElement.htm). You should use this instead of the way you are doing it.

So reference `WebDriver.Support.dll`, put a using for `OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI`:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
```

The `SelectElement` takes an `IWebElement` as a parameter, so it is your responsibility to find the `select` element *first*:

```
IWebElement query_UserType = driver.FindElement(By.Id("user_type"));
var select = new SelectElement(query_UserType);
```

There is then a convience method on this class that allows you to select an `option` within that `select` by it's *visible* `text` property.

```
select.SelectByText("Agent");
```

Similarly, you are trying to find out the currently selected option. The `SelectElement` class can do this easily too:

```
IWebElement selectedOption = select.SelectedOption;
```

Now `SelectedOption` will be an `IWebElement` represting the `option` currently selected within that `select`. So to get it's `text` property, it's nothing different to other elements:

```
selectedOption.Text;
```

Putting it altogether ends up with:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
IWebElement query_UserType = driver.FindElement(By.Id("user_type"));
var select = new SelectElement(query_UserType);
select.SelectByText("Agent");
IWebElement selectedOption = select.SelectedOption;
Console.WriteLine("Currently selected option is: {0}", selectedOption.Text);
```

Comment: It shows error "element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated" in this line:

    select.SelectByText("Agent");

Comment: So what must the user do to make that `select` visible?

Comment: :) thats what I am also confused, how will I make it visible. But it is clearly visible in the browser. There is already another CSS added to this "select", may be that is causing this conflict..

Comment: Is there more than one element with the id of `user_type`? Run `driver.FindElements(By.Id("user_type"));`...it will return a collection, how many items are in that collection?

Comment: No, actually there are not multiple user_type, but the options "Admin", "Agent", "Ops" etc are at two places: first in <a> tag, then, in <select id="user_type">. This is done for design purpose. Would this cause a conflict?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there were 2 elements with the same ID on the webpage. I solved the issue by using  `find element by xpath` instead of `find element by id`.

Answer (score 0):

If this issue appear with Chrome browser only, remove the following command:

```
query_UserType.Clear();
```

I faced the same problem with Chrome and it is fixed after removing clear command.

In case of you really want to delete a text from a text box, try using robot class or any other keyboard simulator and press "backspace"/"delete" button.

Answer (score -1):

This problem also happened to me. The snippet code where I had the problem was:

```
nameProject.clear();        
nameProject.click();
```

Where nameProject is an input text as follow:

```
<input type="textbox" name="project" id="_pt_jobProperties_project">
```

I mapped this input text as follow:

```
@FindBy(id = "_pt_jobProperties_project")
  private WebElement nameProject;
```

I solved it just changing the order of the sentences like bellow:

```
nameProject.clear();        
nameProject.click();
```