# Selenium. Upload a file on a new chrome open file pop up (or how to simulate ctrl+v on python)

Tags: python, selenium, keyboard

Im doing a python selenium script for chrome webdriver, and I need to upload a file. When I hit the upload buttom, a open file dialog pops up, and I haven't been able to actually upload the file. Aproaches I have tried:

Using selenium ide, and recording me uploading the file. It yeilds this result:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("html5_1aq7art6u98a1i1eokfk581u443").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("html5_1aq7art6u98a1i1eokfk581u443").send_keys("")
```

However, the id changes everytime the page is reloaded, and so this aproach doesnt work. I also haven't been able to find a way to locate the form to type the file name.

I also tried using alerts and changing window with selenium

```
driver.switch_to_window("Open")
driver.send_keyssend_keys(os.getcwd()+"/file.png")

alert = driver.switch_to.alert
alert.send_keyssend_keys(os.getcwd()+"/file.png")
```

But both of this aproaches have failed. (the first one doesnt finds the window, and the second one tells me that no alert is open)

As a last resort Im searching how to copy to clipboard the name of the file, and after clicking the upload buttom, wating something like a second, and then simulating with python a "crtl+v" followed by "enter" key press, but I dont know how to do it, and the internet searchs take me to the dark path of some c based third party libraries that overwhelmed me a bit.

Here is the full code for the posting script, the rest of the code (before this part) its just scrapping and deleting my own post:

```
driver.get('https://www.kijiji.ca/p-post-ad.html?categoryId=87')


time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.button--jss-0-514").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("postad-title").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("postad-title").send_keys(postTitle)
driver.find_element_by_id("pstad-descrptn").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("pstad-descrptn").send_keys(postContent)
driver.find_element_by_id("pstad-map-address").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("pstad-map-address").send_keys(postAdress)

#driver.find_element_by_id("ImageUploadButton").click()
#time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file'][contains(@id,'html5_')]").clear()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file'][contains(@id,'html5_')]").send_keys("file.png")
driver.find_element_by_id("PhoneNumber").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("PhoneNumber").send_keys(phoneNumber)
driver.find_element_by_id("pstad-email").send_keys(profile)
driver.find_element_by_name("saveAndCheckout").click()
```

Full Error:
[10360:7760:0815/140356:ERROR:latency_info.cc(164)] RenderWidgetHostImpl::OnSwapCompositorFrame, LatencyInfo vector size 187 is too big.
[10360:7760:0815/140357:ERROR:latency_info.cc(164)] RenderWidgetHostImpl::OnSwapCompositorFrame, LatencyInfo vector size 452 is too big.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "KijijiAutoPosting.py", line 95, in 
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file'][contains(@id,'html5_')]").clear()
  File "C:\Users\Silve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 87, in clear
    self._execute(Command.CLEAR_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\Silve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 461, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Silve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Silve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.116)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)

Comment: here is a screenshot of the upload: http://imgur.com/a/ZtFkN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']").clear()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']").send_keys("/path/to/file")
```

This should work if there is only one button for file uploading.

Also you can try this `XPath`:

```
"//input[@type='file'][contains(@id,'html5_')]"
```

Comment: The thing is, the upload file buttom opens a new chrome pop up asking me for the file, and I havent been able to target that promt. I tried:

driver.find_element_by_id("ImageUploadButton").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("ImageUploadButton").send_keys("img")

but that doesnt do it

Comment: No, target element is not a `button`, but an `input`. Try right click on button -> "inspect" -> right click on `input` -> "Copy" -> "Copy OuterHTML" -> add code to your ticket

Comment: OK, I made it by myself. `HTML` is `<input id="html5_1aq68v6j8md3ei2qhve7l1h053" style="font-size: 999px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;" multiple="" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif,image/bmp" type="file">`. It seems that my code should work. I also added more specific selector

Comment: Im sorry to keep bothering you, here is the link to the upload. Im getting this error: "Message: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated"

I even tried to click the buttom first, and wait a bit before trying the whole clear() and send_leys() and the error persis

Comment: can you provide full code? Maybe there is another problem in your code as I tried my code on https://www.kijiji.ca/p-post-ad.html?categoryId=12 and picture successfuly uploaded....

Comment: Done, for your code, do you use absulute path or relative path? The image is on the same folder as the script. Do you click the button before sending the keys? Im still getting the " invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated" regardeless

Comment: Also, im posting to https://www.kijiji.ca/p-post-ad.html?categoryId=87 I dont know how relevant that is, but the page is slighty different

Comment: You should not click button! You should handle only input field for file upload. Can you also provide full exception log?

Comment: Hey =) solved, for uncanny reasons that go beyong my selenium fu, the 
"driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']").clear()" was causing the error 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192149/selenium-with-net-invalid-element-state-element-is-not-currently-interactable